# Couldnot add more than a single data in map

Tags: flutter, dart

i have created a map as below:

```
 Map<String, GenreData> map = new HashMap();
```

And i am getting data from API  but i only one data is being added in map.There are more data in api.

```
            for (var genderdata in snapshot.data.data.data) {
              hashmap = {genderdata.name:genderdata};

            }
```

I am trying to map name(value) and craft(key). So that i can categorized the NAME based on  CRAFT.

Here is my json

```
   {
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5f3d60b5494f5f003e26af7d",
            "name": "Art & Design",
            "craft": "DIGITAL_ARTIST",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:26:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "updatedAt": "Tue Sep 01 2020 14:56:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "id": "5f3d60b5494f5f003e26af7d"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3d6109494f5f003e26af7f",
            "name": "Beauty",
            "craft": "DIGITAL_ARTIST",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:27:38 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5f3d6109494f5f003e26af7f"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3d619e494f5f003e26af87",
            "name": "Hip Hop",
            "craft": "MUSIC",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:30:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "updatedAt": "Tue Sep 01 2020 14:59:48 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "id": "5f3d619e494f5f003e26af87"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3d621f494f5f003e26af8b",
            "name": "Punk",
            "craft": "MUSIC",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:32:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5f3d621f494f5f003e26af8b"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3d6254494f5f003e26af8d",
            "name": "Pop",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:33:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "craft": "MUSIC",
            "updatedAt": "Tue Sep 01 2020 15:02:39 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "id": "5f3d6254494f5f003e26af8d"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3d62ad494f5f003e26af91",
            "name": "R & B",
            "craft": "MUSIC",
            "createdAt": "Wed Aug 19 2020 17:34:37 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "__v": 0,
            "updatedAt": "Tue Sep 01 2020 15:04:13 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "id": "5f3d62ad494f5f003e26af91"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please post your response json

Comment: Updated question with my json file @Godslave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `= {}` you are clearing the map and then inserting the current item.

Instead, use:

```dart
for (var genderData in snapshot.data.data.data) {
  hashmap.putIfAbsent(genderData.name, () => genderData);
}
```

If you need more information about `putIfAbsent`, check the [api](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html). And about `HashMap`, [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html).

Comment: Thanks that really did the work @MDDG .Can you tell me how can i Categorized as i mention in question too

Comment: Then you need a `List<String>` as a value. Then, you have to use `hashmap.putIfAbsent(genderData.craft, []).add(genderData.name)`. If the key you are adding is new, it creates an empty list. Then, to the value returned (a filled or empty list) it adds the value (`add(genderData.name)`). Is this what you are asking for?